# Is Core animation not possible in an today extension

Tags: ios, core-animation, today-extension

I'm building an today extension (widget) in iOS and was hoping it would be possible to add some subtle animations. Specifically i'm trying to transition a text label when the text changes.

My code works as expected in a regular app, but not in the widget. The text changes, but there is no transition.

```
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.duration = 3.0;
    animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [self.heading.layer addAnimation:animation forKey: nil];
    self.heading.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
```

This snippet is run inside the viewDidAppear method

Comment: What other differences are there between your animation use in the app and the widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreAnimation should definitely be available from extensions. Any API that isn't available from within an extension should have its declaration marked with NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE (visible in the API's header file).

Comment: Not sure what caused it to not function properly, but i've experienced som bugs with the extensions in iOS 8 before as well. Marked this as an answer because of the useful NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE

Comment: The best thing to do in that case would be to file a bug using Bug Reporter with good reproduce steps (attaching an example project demonstrating the bug would be absolutely perfect).
https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/using-bug-reporter